# using awk and printf in for loop bash

Tags: bash, awk

How can I use awk and printf in for loop?

Here is my code

```
for fileName in /home/BamFiles/sample*
do
       sampleIds=${fileName##*/}

    for Bam in /home/BamFiles/sample*/*.bam
    do
        samtools idxstats $Bam | awk '{i+=$3+$4} END {printf("%s\t%d",$sampleIds Bam)}'
    done

 done
```

I get the the following error

```
 awk: fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
 `%d    %s'
     ^ ran out for this one
```

Expected output is

```
  sample1  52432
  sample2  32909
  sample3  54000
  sample5  45890
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk can never be able to expand a shell variable. You are also trying to pass only a single argument to printf (nothing is passed for `%d`.

Perhaps you want it this way:

```
samtools idxstats "$Bam" | awk -v "file=$fileName" '{i+=$3+$4} END {printf("%s\t%d\n", file, i)}'
```

Note that embedding a variable's value directly to awk's code may be possible by using double-quotes but is not recommended:

```
samtools idxstats "$Bam" | awk "{i+=\$3+\$4} END {printf(\"%s\\t%d\", $file, i)}"
```

Suggestion:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for sample in /home/BamFiles/sample*; do
    for bam in "$sample"/*.bam; do
        samtools idxstats "$bam"
    done | awk -v sample="${sample##*/}" '{ i += $3 + $4 } END { printf("%s\t%d\n", sample, i) }'
done
```

Or

```
shopt -s nullglob
for sample in /home/BamFiles/sample*; do
    for bam in "$sample"/*.bam; do
        samtools idxstats "$bam" | \
            awk -v sample="${sample##*/}" -v bam="${bam##*/}" \
                '{ i += $3 + $4 } END { printf("%s\t%s\t%d\n", sample, bam, i) }'
    done
done
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was suppose to pass sampleIds to %d so I have edited it.

Comment: @hash Can you try my suggestions?

Comment: When you tried my first suggestion you probably omitted \ or added a space after it. I modified it to just run it as a line.